# Getting the display value for a form option with webform 3.x while processing submissions

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I want to create an associative array of submitted form data and do some additional processing on the submitted data (namely send the data over http POST). I have the following code:

```
function webformssalesforce_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (substr($form_id, 0, 20) == 'webform_client_form_') {
        // Add the submit handler after the existing Webform submit handler,
        // but before the second Webform handler. Pop off the first one and add
        // ours second.
        $first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'webformssalesforce_client_submit');
      }


}

function webformssalesforce_client_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);

    $fields =  Array();
    foreach($form_state["values"]["submitted_tree"] as $key=>$value) { 
        if(! is_array ( $value)){
            $fields[$key] = $value; 
        }
    }

    //do stuff with $fields


}
```

This works fine for text and email fields, however for select elements I get the option's safe_value instead of the display value for the select. So for example if an element has the folowing options:

```
1|Display value 1
2|Display value 2
3|Display value 3
```

How can I get the display value instead of the safe_value (Display value 2 instead of 2) for an element?

I'm pretty sure this code worked fine for me with a previous version of webform.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue, could not find a predefined function and ended up writing one that loops over the select options in the text area and returns an associative array.

The basic principle is described in this article:
http://blog.raisedeyebrow.com/2009/01/displaying-webform-results-in-a-block/

For my project I used the webform_submission_insert hook instead of form_alter, but I hope it works for the variables that you have available in form_alter as well.

If it is likely that you'll need this feature more often you may want to use a function to extract the data for any textarea using the same principle.

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {

   switch ($node->title) {

    case "Test form":

    $options = array();

    // fill options field with options from select textarea via custom function;
    // field number of my particular webform select field is 12, hence:
    $options = _extract_select_options ($node->webform['components'][12]['extra']['items']);

    // output key and value of chosen select option
    $chosen = $options[$submission->data[12]['value'][0]]);
    drupal_set_message ("key / value: ".$submission->data[12]['value'][0]." / ".$chosen;

    break;
   }
}

// declare function with text area content as parameter
function _extract_select_options ($mytext) {

    $options = $pairs = $temp_array = array();

    // split text into chunks after each line-break;
    // if not visible here, use "backslash n" as explode parameter
    $pairs = explode("\n", $mytext);

    // split each line into pairs of key and value
    foreach($pairs as $pair) {
      $temp_array = explode('|', $pair);
      $options[trim($temp_array[0])] = $temp_array[1];
    }

    return $options;

}
```